# Monitor message sent status launched by Intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am looking for a way to monitor the sent status of a MMS message started by `Intent.ACTION_SEND` so that I can return to my original activity upon the message being sent. Currently Im using  `startActivityForResult()` with a request code to start it so theres something to return and display a toast with and I'm also using `Intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true)` so that it exits the default messenger and returns to the original activity when the Send button is pressed but that only gives the illusion that it sent the message and doesn't actually monitor and wait for it to be sent. I have found examples that monitor sms messages that use the `smsManager`, pending intents, and broadcast receivers, but being a noob I'm uncertain if thats the approach I should use. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to monitor the sent status of a MMS message started by Intent.ACTION_SEND so that I can return to my original activity upon the message being sent.

That is not possible. First, you have no control over what activity the user chooses to handle your `ACTION_SEND`. Second, it would be up to the authors of that other activity how to implement a "send" operation, and how they do that is none of your business.

> Currently Im using startActivityForResult()

`ACTION_SEND` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`; you will not generally get a result.

> I'm also using Intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true)

Whatever that is, that is undocumented, unsupported, and generally ignored by most implementers of `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: and all of the above is why I was asking for a better approach. I know its not currently set up properly and thats why I mentioned it all in the posting but its simulating the result Im looking for, that the message was sent and it automatically returns to the original activity. All I need to know is when its done or if its not possible at all, seems Im out of luck though.

Comment: @user1409172: "All I need to know is when its done or if its not possible at all, seems Im out of luck though" -- unless there is some other way to send MMS, yes. With SMS, sending through `SmsManager` allows you to provide a `PendingIntent` to find out when it has been sent.

Comment: Gotcha, stuck using MMS, really wish there was more support for it like the `SmsManager` etc.