# Invalid recipient on putting intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent",true)

Tags: android, android-intent, vcf-vcard

I am somehow getting an error that the recipient is invalid for the first time when I try to try to pass some information to the messaging app.

There are two scenarios:

1) This is working when there's not put extra for exit_to_sent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/x-vCard");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, vCardString);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", phone);
        sendIntent.putExtra("name", "Contact");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

2) This is not working when there's put extra for exit_to_sent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/x-vCard");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, vCardString);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", phone);
        sendIntent.putExtra("name", "Contact");
        sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Any suggestions why it's happening. Cause according to the documentation, exit_to_sent should work if you are going back to you app after the message is sent.

Any help will be appreciated..:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the semantics of the messaging app, but is that a typo using the variable name "i" instead of "sendIntent" or I am just missing something? You must be instantiating sendIntent somewhere, otherwise you'd get a NPE. So, just asking. Thanks.

I also think you meant to say "exit_on_sent" in your description. But it seems that parameter may be ignored by implementors. See the answer here:

[Monitor message sent status launched by Intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628006/monitor-message-sent-status-launched-by-intent-new-intentintent-action-send)

Comment: Sorry .. that was a typo while asking this question.thanks for noticing

Comment: That post didn't really answer the question though cause the issue is not really with the code..somehow, the android is not accepting the exit_on_send on that particular device. The code is working fine on other devices.